# Cannot send the email using PHPMailer library

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer library.
I want to use yahoo send an email to the gmail.
Below are the code that I tried:

**testemail.php**

```
<?php
require_once('./PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'testllk@yahoo.com';
$mail->Password = 'a1b2c3d4e5';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

$from = $mail->Username;
$fromName = 'llktest';
$toList = 'testllk@gmail.com';
$subject = 'PHPMailer test';
$body = 'Hi, everyone.<br />';
$body .= 'I am performing <i>PHPMailer test</i>.';

$mail->SetFrom($from, $fromName);
$mail->AddReplyTo($from, $fromName);

foreach($toList as $to)
{
    $mail->AddAddress($to);
}

$mail->Subject=$subject;
$mail->MsgHTML($body);

if(!$mail->Send())
{
    echo 'Mailer Error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
    echo 'Message sent!';
}
?>
```

After I write the above code, I create a new yahoo account (testllk@yahoo.com).
After I create a yahoo account, I run the testemail.php on the web page. 
However, I get the error below:

```
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
```

Why I can't send the email? 
Is my coding problem or yahoo setting problem? 
 Any idea?

Comment: Can you try commenting out the line `$mail->isSMTP();`?

Comment: you could try port 587, should a firewall block your outgoing connection

Comment: You're using an old version of PHPMailer; get the latest, and read the docs that the error messages link you to.